# Cyclomatic complexity for method is too high

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

How do i refactor my code to fix the lint error i am getting?

```
  def value=(val)
    if val
      if [:char].include?(@type) && val.length >= args[:limit] && val == 'true'
        val = 'Y'
      elsif [:char].include?(@type) && val.length >= args[:limit] && val == 'false'
        val = 'N'
      elsif [:bit].include?(@type) && val.length >= args[:limit] && val == 'true'
        val = 1
      elsif [:bit].include?(@type) && val.length >= args[:limit] && val == 'false'
        val = 0
      elsif [:varchar, :char, :nvarchar].include?(@type) && @args[:limit]
        unless val.length <= args[:limit]
          msg = "The length of #{@name} exceeds the max limit #{@args[:limit]}"
          raise Programmability::BadRequestError.new(nil, msg)
        end
      elsif [:numeric].include?(@type) && @args[:precision] && @args[:scale]
        valid_numeric?(val, @args[:precision], @args[:scale])
      elsif [:datetime].include?(@type)
        valid_date?(val)
      end
    end
    @value = val
  end
```

Comment: Does this code run as expected or is there a bug you are currently facing?

Comment: It runs as expected. just trying to fix the lint error

Comment: The title is too common and generic for this site. Also, you haven't given us enough context about what this function aims to achieve for us to give you a good code review. Please read [ask] and edit both the title and the body of the question.

Comment: You would probably need to break it up into methods, maybe `convert_bool`, `convert_numeric`, etc. The `unless` inside the `if` is probably what is causing the most issues so consider trying to remove that. Lastly I would write `if @type==:char; val = convert_bool(val) ? 'Y' : 'N'`

Answer (score 1):

- `[x].include?(y)` is the most roundabout way I've ever seen of saying `x == y`.
- You're repeating `val.length >= args[:limit]` for almost every. single. case.
- Why is there an instance variable called `@args`? That smells like you didn't bother to actually handle things in the constructor, and instead just store everything for later. Also, why are you using `@args` directly, when it seems you also have a reader/accessor method, `args`? Using the accessor is better, though you can use either - just *don't mix them*.
- Why isn't there code after the calls to `valid_numeric?` and `valid_date?`? The prefix `valid_...` and the `?` in the names indicate that those methods (should!) return boolean values. But if they do, you're ignoring it - which doesn't make sense. So it smells like those methods don't so much validate anything, but actually *set `@value` to something*. No thanks.
- You're overwriting the argument `val`, which isn't pretty. Make a new local variable instead, or write to `@value` directly.
- What if `val` is just `false`? Not the word, but the boolean? In that case all the logic will be skipped, and you'll go straight to `@val = false`. It doesn't matter whatever `@type` is, or whatever `args[:limit]` is. I think you want your `if` to check for `val.nil?` specifically.

It seems like what you really want is 4-6 different *classes* to handle different datatypes. Whatever you're trying to do, you're doing too much of it in one method and one class.

Comment: I created a new method for val == 'true' and val == 'false' but new method also throws same error. please see updated question

Comment: @User7354632781 You'll want to log in as "jose" if you want edit your question. However, you cannot add code to your question once it's been answered; please see [the help section](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If you want to ask a follow-up question, just post a new one - it's encouraged!

Answer (score 0):

Off course I think you should rewrite all the related code to make this method readable. But I can suggest such kind of refactor without rewriting related methods:

```
def value=(val)
  case @type
  when :char
    val = {'true' => 'Y', 'false' => 'N'}[val] if val.length >= args[:limit]
  when :bit
    val = {'true' => 1, 'false' => 0}[val] if val.length >= args[:limit]
  when :numeric
    valid_numeric?(val, @args[:precision], @args[:scale]) if @args[:precision] && @args[:scale]
  when :datetime
    valid_date?(val)
  else # [:varchar, :char, :nvarchar]
    if val.length > args[:limit]
      raise Programmability::BadRequestError.new(nil, "The length of #{@name} exceeds the max limit #{@args[:limit]}")
    end
  end
  @value = val
end
```

Btw I assume that methods `valid_numeric?` and `valid_date?` mutate argument passed to them, so they should be named like `validate_numeric` (maybe even `process_numeric`), and not mutate, but return resulted numeric.
And I would off course rewrite it all to something like:

```
  def value=(val)
    @value = case @type
             when :char
               process_char(val)
             when :bit
               process_bit(val)
             when :numeric
               process_numeric(val)
             when :datetime
               process_date(val)
             else # [:varchar, :char, :nvarchar]
               process_other_chars(val)
             end
  end

  def process_char(char)
      {'true' => 'Y', 'false' => 'N'}[char] if char.length >= args[:limit] || char
  end

  def process_bit(bit)
    {'true' => 1, 'false' => 0}[bit] if bit.length >= args[:limit] || bit
  end

  def process_other_chars(char)
    if val.length > args[:limit]
      raise Programmability::BadRequestError.new(nil, "The length of #{@name} exceeds the max limit #{@args[:limit]}")
    end
  end

  def process_numeric(numeric)
    #check of @args[:precision] && @args[:scale] should be within method
    #...
  end

  def process_datetime(datetime)
    #...
  end
```